# GAE Blobstore API Upload Progress Tracking

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I'm looking for a way to track progress of an upload using Google App Engine's Blobstore API. I don't see anything mentioned in the documentation, but I'm curious if anyone knows if this is possible. I have a feeling that I might have to move over to using GCS for uploads instead to get this functionality. Any insight?

Comment: It seems there's been a public issue tracker [Feature Request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2921) open for this for some time now, however given the age, and the fact that, as you observe, this functionality is available in Cloud Storage, I'd recommend simply migrating to Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I noticed that and hoped that due to the age of it, that this might have already been resolved.